# How to get PDF from HTML Page (UIWebView)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, airprint

i want to know how to get the PDF from HTML page.

Im using the Method

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(self.filePath, CGRectZero, nil);    //creating PDF

    int i = 0;
    for (; i < pages; i++)
    {
        if (pageHeight * (i+1) > height)
        {
            CGRect f = [myWebPage frame];
            f.size.height -= (((i+1) * pageHeight) - height);
            [myWebPage setFrame: f];
        }
        // Specify the size of the pdf page
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, width, pageHeight), nil);
        CGContextRef currentContext =  UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [[[myWebPage subviews] lastObject] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, pageHeight * i) animated:NO];
        [myWebPage.layer renderInContext: currentContext];
        NSLog(@"I = %d",i);
    }

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
[[[myWebPage subviews] lastObject] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
[myWebPage setFrame:origframe];
```

But this will not give the proper PDF as some of the part of multipage PDF is clipped and it  is crashing the application if it take more then 10 seconds.

I have downloaded https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf this file and used NDHTMLtoPDF.h and NDHTMLtoPDF.m files..

its working fine..

but when i tried using the individual functions like

```
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
if (webView.isLoading) return;

UIPrintPageRenderer *render = [[UIPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];

[render addPrintFormatter:webView.viewPrintFormatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];

CGRect printableRect = CGRectMake(self.pageMargins.left,
                              self.pageMargins.top,
                              self.pageSize.width - self.pageMargins.left - self.pageMargins.right,
                              self.pageSize.height - self.pageMargins.top - self.pageMargins.bottom);

CGRect paperRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.pageSize.width, self.pageSize.height);

[render setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:paperRect] forKey:@"paperRect"];
[render setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:printableRect] forKey:@"printableRect"];

NSData *pdfData = [render printToPDF];

[pdfData writeToFile: self.PDFpath  atomically: YES];

[self terminateWebTask];

if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(HTMLtoPDFDidSucceed:)])
    [self.delegate HTMLtoPDFDidSucceed:self];


}
```

and

```
- (NSData*) printToPDF
{
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData( pdfData, self.paperRect, nil );

[self prepareForDrawingPages: NSMakeRange(0, self.numberOfPages)];

CGRect bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds();

for ( int i = 0 ; i < self.numberOfPages ; i++ )
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    [self drawPageAtIndex: i inRect: bounds];
}

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

return pdfData;
}
```

its showing the error in place

```
NSData *pdfData = [render printToPDF];
[self prepareForDrawingPages: NSMakeRange(0, self.numberOfPages)];
[self drawPageAtIndex: i inRect: bounds];
```

As it is not able to locate the functions and variables.

but in the code they didnt declare any variables like numberOfPages and all but they are getting the solution but im getting the error..

can anyone please send me the proper code and steps to get the print formate of HTML file to PDF which uses UIPrintPageRenderer.

Please help me..

Comment: check this [Tutorial](http://www.ioslearner.com/convert-html-uiwebview-pdf-iphone-ipad/)

Answer (score 2):

//Pass HTML string here

```
 NSString *str_PDFName_path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/Library/MyFile.pdf"];
    self.PDFCreator = [NDHTMLtoPDF createPDFWithHTML:str_HTML pathForPDF:[str_PDFName_path stringByExpandingTildeInPath] delegate:self pageSize:kPaperSizeA4 margins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 5, 90, 5)];
```

//after doing this

```
- (NSData*) printToPDF
{
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
    //595, 842
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectMake(0, 20, 595, 842), nil);

   // [self prepareForDrawingPages: NSMakeRange(0, self.numberOfPages)];

    //CGRect bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds();

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < self.numberOfPages ; i++ )
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

        [self drawPageAtIndex: i inRect: CGRectMake(120, 770, 500, 15)]; //bounds];
        //CGRect textRect = [self addText:@"Centurion Medical Products | 100 Centurion Way | Williamston MI USA 48895 | 800.248.4058"
        //                      withFrame:CGRectMake(120, 770, 500, 15) fontSize:8.0f];
        CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 99/255.f, 100/255.f, 99/255.f, 1.0f);

        [self addText:@"Medical Products | 100 Centurion Way | Williamston MI USA 48895 | 800.248.4058"
                              withFrame:CGRectMake(130, 770, 500, 15) fontSize:8.0f];
        UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.gif"];
        //CGRect imageRect = [self addImage:anImage
        //                          atPoint:CGPointMake(50, 768)];
        [self addImage:anImage atPoint:CGPointMake(50, 768)];
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    return pdfData;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. but i don't want to use NDHTMLtoPDF.h and NDHTMLtoPDF.m classes..